# Recursive Math in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sqlite, math

I apologize if I am not using the right term.

Anyway, I have two tables. One is an item table with a id and value. The second is a mod table with a link to the item table and a modifier.  There may be multiple modifiers for any given item.  If item.value is 100 and two modifiers are linked with that item (say with mod.modifier value of 1.25 and 1.1) I would like to get the value 137.5 (100 *1.25 *1.1) rather than 135 (100 *(1.25+1.1)).

This is the test code I have written so far:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS item;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mod;

CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    value DECIMAL
);

CREATE TABLE mod (
    mod_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    item_id INTEGER,
    modifier DECIMAL
);

INSERT INTO item (item_id, value)
    VALUES (0, 100);
INSERT INTO item (item_id, value)
    VALUES (1, 10);
INSERT INTO item (item_id, value)
    VALUES (2, 1000);

INSERT INTO mod (mod_id, item_id, modifier)
    VALUES (0, 0, 0.25);
INSERT INTO mod (mod_id, item_id, modifier)
    VALUES (1, 0, 0.10);
INSERT INTO mod (mod_id, item_id, modifier)
    VALUES (2, 2, 0.10);
INSERT INTO mod (mod_id, item_id, modifier)
    VALUES (3, 2, 0.05);
INSERT INTO mod (mod_id, item_id, modifier)
    VALUES (4, 2, 0.15);

SELECT item.item_id ID, item.value Value, mod.modifier Mod
    FROM item
    LEFT JOIN mod
    ON item.item_id = mod.item_id;
```

I hope to get a result like:

```
item.item_id    item.value      Result
0               100             137.5
1               10              10
2               1000            1328.25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I know MySQL lacks a built-in aggregate function like this one.  You can construct it:

```
SELECT item.item_id ID, item.value Value, EXP(SUM(LOG10(mod.modifier)), 10) Mod
    FROM item
    LEFT JOIN mod
    ON item.item_id = mod.item_id
GROUP BY item.item_id;
```

Because log() maps addition into multiplication.

Comment: I know this will work, but it looks like SQLite doesn't allow LOG or LOG10 functions. I've been trying to add in the extension-functions.c file which should give me those functions but I've had no luck yet.  Alternatively I could create a another table which stores the LOG10 of the mod.modifier.  I would have to manually calculate that but I think it could work.  Is there any other way I could do this?

Comment: +1 . . . This is the correct answer for the question which was about MySQL and not about SQLite.

Comment: Whoops. I thought SQLite was a database for MySQL. My mistake. I'll start a new question after I do a bit more research. Thanks.

Comment: @KeiNagase -- if you're going to be adding functions, why not add a PROD aggregator?